# How to specify two different and separate conditions in query builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, query, definition-query

For example, I have a table containing well log data for multiple operable units.  I would like to make a query outputting a table where Operable unit=001 OR 002, AND Formation= Residuum.  I would like to first select only values where operable unit equals 001 or 002, and then from those values select only those where the formation=residuum.

Currently the output from [OU] = '001' OR '002' AND [Formation] = 'Residuum', will output a table that will include other operable units as long as the formation=residuum.

I am using ArcMap 10.

Comment: Did you try using parentheses?  `([OU] = '001' OR [OU]= '002') AND [Formation] = 'Residuum' ` ?

Comment: [OU] IN ('001', '002') AND [Formation] = 'Residuum'

Comment: I like Richard's better.

Comment: The expression using IN worked for me.  Thank you very much for your help! @RichardFairhurst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this just so you can mark this format as the answer.

The IN syntax is the most compact way to write the expression you want:

[OU] IN ('001', '002') AND [Formation] = 'Residuum'

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an expression like this would work better:

**[OU] = '001' AND [Formation] = 'Residuum' OR [OU] = '002' AND [Formation] = 'Residuum'**

It's a little tedious in its formatting, but should return the results that you're after.

A little more elegant expression would be:

**([OU] = '001' OR [OU] = '002') AND [Formation] = 'Residuum'**

Either one should produce the same result.

Comment: Thank you!  Both of these expressions worked.  It is interesting to me that ([OU]='001' OR '002') will output a different expression than ([OU]='001' OR [OU]='002').  It seems to me I need to learn a little more about the logic of SQL.